# Gauss circle problem not being correctly computed when r = sqrt(18)

Tags: javascript, math, computational-geometry

I've been stuck on the Gauss circle problem, so I tried to implement the Wikipedia solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem.

This is the exact form I'm trying to implement, so I can use it to compute the solution of the Gauss circle problem:

[image]

I've already tried implement this in JavaScript and Kotlin (I was not sure if JavaScript floats were reliable to make this computation but both are not working):

```js
const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 100

function computeSummationElement(r, i) {
  return Math.floor(r ** 2 / (4 * i + 1)) - Math.floor(r ** 2 / (4 * i + 3));
}

function summation(r, precision = DEFAULT_PRECISION) {
  // Create each element of the summation.
  const elements = Array.from({ length: precision });

  // For each element compute it's value.
  const computed = elements.map((_, i) => computeSummationElement(r, i))

  // Sum all elements.
  return computed.reduce((acc, current) => acc + current, 0)
}

function points(r, precision = DEFAULT_PRECISION) {
  return 1 + 4 * summation(r, precision)
}

points(4) // 49
points(Math.sqrt(17)) // 57
points(Math.sqrt(18)) // 57, why? expected: 61
points(Math.sqrt(20)) // 69
points(5) // 81
```

Expected outputs:

```
       N(4) = 49
N(sqrt(17)) = 57
N(sqrt(18)) = 61
N(sqrt(20)) = 69
       N(5) = 81
```

Where am I missing?

Comment: Hint: what does `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(18)**2)` give you?

Comment: `Math.sqrt(18)**2 == 17.999999999999996` thus `Math.floor(it) == 17`, we got him.

Comment: Base the computation on r² instead of r.

Comment: This is just an workaround to the problem: "well, if it's not working with `r`, use `r²`"; the right solution, as Mark pointed, would be to use BigNumbers to increase the decimal precision required to compute this problem, but thanks anyways!